# An array in getoptions in Perl

Tags: perl

Is it possible to have one option as an array, instead of a scalar variable?

Like, I want to take a filename as an option, with '-file' and user will enter with wildcards, like, "tmp*.txt".  Now I want to store what matches this "tmp*.txt" in an array.  Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, see `Getopt::Std` http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html and `Getopt::long` http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. But you can `glob` this argument before use, which will do almost what you want:

```
my @files = glob $options{file};
foreach my $file (@files) {
    ...
}
```

In case your argument did not contain any globbing characters like `*`, it will work as before. But if you have provided `*`, globbing will expand automatically.

The only downside of this is that you have to quote parameter in single or double quotes like: `-file "tmp*.txt"`, otherwise shell will interpolate your globbing.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. But why do you want to store it in a List?

Anyway, here is how you store it in a Array:

```
my @list = ('FILE',);
print $list[0]; # prints FILE
```